# Blender, eevee, lighting, banding, artifacting with volumetric lighting

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, artifacts

I'm doing volumetric lighting with eevee and outputting sequences in 16-bit RAW as opposed to png.

This reduced a lot of banding artifacts over pngs and looks okay other than flickering lights-- however upon outputting even with very low to almost no compression of these files, banding is heavily in the lights lighting up the area.

I know export settings- I work in film. I know it's probably due to how I'm rendering out in Blender, but I'm so confused why the lights that are inside or near an object's surface cause flickering, and I'm so confused why there's this crazy banding issue when rendering PNGS as opposed to RAW photo formats.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about from a render test-- again for some reason when outputting from the RAW in premiere and After effects, it increases the banding by soooo much- the artifacting on the building and the light flickering is there though in the playback of the RAW:

vimeo.com/504194617/f5518a783f

I should also clarify- I'm seeing people using volumetric lighting with eevee and getting cleaner results without banding. I'm trying to pinpoint what I'm doing wrong: density-- .01 anisotropy .5 lights I'm using are occasionally placed inside of objects to make them glow. In my case it's adding banding. as soon as i turn off the atmospheric lighting, the banding issues go away

Comment: If you work on film you should be familiar with EXR. Why bother with pngs?

Comment: And don''t think that RAW has any resemblance to RAW photo formats.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with EXR. Thank you for the information. Ultimately for where I need this to go online, I'm going to have to bounce it to a different file container and I'm wondering how to eliminate the banding. I'll do an EXR test- will get rid of the lights flickering? I'm having that as an issue and I imagine it's an eevee limitation or I'm doing something wrong since it's not happening in cycles.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I thought that is what the RAW meant.

Comment: I should also clarify- I'm seeing people using volumetric lighting with eevee and getting cleaner results without banding. I'm trying to pinpoint what I'm doing wrong:

density-- .01 anisotropy .5

lights I'm using are occasionally placed inside of objects to make them glow. In my case it's adding banding. as soon as i turn off the atmospheric lighting, the banding issues go away

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183180/does-the-compositor-affect-image-quality/183185#183185

Comment: Eevee's volumetrics are quite limited...also, you have a lot of problems with z-figthing on the rooftop of the station.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164368/unwanted-flickering-in-rendered-animation/164393#164393